# Python is Not running my For Loop more than once

Tags: python

So i have been searching this for a few days now as well as trying everything i can think of to iron this out..

I have added print statements in trying to figure out whats causing this error and it looks like my for statement wont run more than once I am not seeing the error though, i am hoping someone here can see something i cant.

Here is the part that wont run more than once:

```
for row in csv_reader1:
                print("Searching for City Coordinates In Other File")
                if f'{row["shapeid"]}' == shapeidInt:
                    print("Found City in Coordinates File")
                    if coordString == "none":
                        print("First in City")
                        coordString = f'({row["ycoords"]} {row["xcoords"]}'
                    else:
                        print("Not First in City")
                        coordString += f', {row["ycoords"]} {row["xcoords"]}'

                else:
                    print("Shapeid is not shapeidInt")
```

Here is the Full Code:

```
import csv
import os

shapeidInt = "0123456"
labelString = "none"
coordString = "none"

if os.path.exists("Output.txt"):
  os.remove("Output.txt")

with open('nodesfake.csv', mode='r') as nodes_file, open('driver-attributes.csv', mode='r') as driver_attributes_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(driver_attributes_file)
    print("Starting")
    for row in csv_reader:
        print("Searching for a City")
        shapeidInt = f'{row["shapeid"]}'
        labelString = f'{row["LABEL"]}'
        if shapeidInt == "":
            print("Blank Found")
            continue
        else:

            print("Found and Loading a City" + f'{row["shapeid"]}')
            csv_reader1 = csv.DictReader(nodes_file)
            for row in csv_reader1:
                print("Searching for City Coordinates In Other File")
                if f'{row["shapeid"]}' == shapeidInt:
                    print("Found City in Coordinates File")
                    if coordString == "none":
                        print("First in City")
                        coordString = f'({row["ycoords"]} {row["xcoords"]}'
                    else:
                        print("Not First in City")
                        coordString += f', {row["ycoords"]} {row["xcoords"]}'

                else:
                    print("Shapeid is not shapeidInt")

            f = open("Output.txt", "a+")
            print("Appending File")
            f.write(f'SET @' + labelString + '= ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(\r\n')
            f.write("  'POLYGON(\r\n")
            coordString += ")\r\n"
            f.write(coordString)
            f.write("  )'\r\n")
            f.write(');\r\n')

            f.close()



    print("=======================Finished=======================")
    print(f'=====================Check Output=====================')
```

Example Output:

```
Starting
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City0
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Found City in Coordinates File
First in City
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Found City in Coordinates File
Not First in City
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Found City in Coordinates File
Not First in City
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Found City in Coordinates File
Not First in City
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Found City in Coordinates File
Not First in City
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Found City in Coordinates File
Not First in City
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Found City in Coordinates File
Not First in City
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Searching for City Coordinates In Other File
Shapeid is not shapeidInt
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City1
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City1.1
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City1.2
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City1.3
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City1.4
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City1.5
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City2
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City2.0.ring1
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City3
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City4
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City5
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City6
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City7
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City8
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City9
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City10
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City11
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City12
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City13
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City14
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City15
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City16
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City17
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City18
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City19
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City20
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City21
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City22
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City23
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City24
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City24.1
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City24.2
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City25
Appending File
Searching for a City
Blank Found
Searching for a City
Found and Loading a City26
Appending File
=======================Finished=======================
=====================Check Output=====================

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.591 s
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**EDIT::**
im sorry i hope this is what you meant by more complete and verifiable @Pelipap
unfortunatly this is as minimal as i can come up with.

I am trying to loop through driver-attributes.csv and get the shapeid + Label
then use that to search through nodesfake.csv for that specific shapeid and get all coordinates and print them into a file as such:

```
SET @Ash Township= ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(
  'POLYGON(
(42.03516778 -83.41969026, 42.03679795 -83.41973153, 42.04044454 -83.4198216, 42.04155794 -83.41981444, 42.0440793 -83.41985152, 42.0452773 -83.41985275, 42.0466032 -83.41988936)
  )'
);
```

Example of driver-attributes.csv:

```
shapeid,OBJECTID,FIPSCODE,FIPSNUM,NAME,LABEL,TYPE,SQKM,SQMILES,ACRES,VER,LAYOUT,PENINSULA,ShapeSTAre,ShapeSTLen
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
0,961,3680,3680,Ash,Ash Township,Township,90.159,34.81,22278.523,17A,landscape,lower,163750009.8,52066.60235
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,965,7720,7720,Berlin,Berlin Township,Township,84.898,32.779,20978.464,17A,landscape,lower,154060891.4,95099.85825
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1.1,965,7720,7720,Berlin,Berlin Township,Township,84.898,32.779,20978.464,17A,landscape,lower,154060891.4,95099.85825
```

Example od nodesfake.csv:

```
shapeid,xcoords,ycoords
,,
0,-83.41969026,42.03516778
,,
0,-83.41973153,42.03679795
,,
0,-83.4198216,42.04044454
,,
0,-83.41981444,42.04155794
,,
0,-83.41985152,42.0440793
,,
0,-83.41985275,42.0452773
,,
0,-83.41988936,42.0466032
,,
1,-83.23384725,41.99454614
,,
1,-83.23398864,41.99444096
,,
1,-83.24133912,41.97833409
```

Comment: There must only be one row returned by `csv_reader1`.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a [mcve]

Comment: @Pelipap You can type `[mcve]` to generate a link for a related concept by the way: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate both 'driver-attributes.csv' and 'nodesfake.csv'. What you probably want to do is for every row of 'driver-attributes.csv' to open 'nodesfake.csv' and iterate from beginning.
Move `with open('nodesfake.csv', mode='r') as nodes_file` just before `csv_reader1 = csv.DictReader(nodes_file)` !

Comment: Ok so thank you that was correct as well as both files were using the name "shapeid" when i did your suggestion as well as changed the 2nd file to use "shapeid2" it works great! i truly appreciate your help!